# Define array type in Python to be filled by C function

Tags: python, c, arrays, ctypes

In the `C` header "`param1`" is declared as an `OUT` parameter:

```
long A_API test( 
                        ___OUT_ char param1
                   )
```

In the `Python` code I am trying to use array so that `test` function has space to fill this parameter.I have imported `ctpyes` and:

```
test_array = bytearray(b'')
importArray = (ctypes.c_char*40)(*test_array)

def callTest():
    result = lib.test(importArray)
    return result
```

But `test` function doesn't get executed and it fails somewhere.

Unfortunately I only have `.so` file and not the source code so I can't debug the code but I assume I have type define issue here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This `___OUT_` is not part of C, what is this macro defined to?

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect.  Is that the way it is in the actual code?  Copy and paste the error you're getting.

Comment: Out param is a char but you try to mangle with a bytearray.

Comment: Also, `param1` is most likely a pointer or array parameter, there is no way to define `___OUT_` (which seems to be Windows stuff) such that `param1` can actually act as an "out" parameter.

Comment: Thanks @bav. How can I change my code?

Comment: Could you pleas give me feedback on my question?why did I get down mark?

Comment: Your question as it stands can not be answered without guessing, see for example my request for clarification. It doesn't contain the minimal, complete example that it should, so its use for others with similar problems it very limited. Hence the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python code should be something that according to function definition:

```
out_char = ctypes.c_char()
result = lib.test(ctypes.byref(out_char))
```